# AES encryption using phpseclib

Tags: php, encryption, aes, phpseclib

Can someone help me with AES? I've used phpseclib  in encrypting and decrypting the data, however, it seems that it couldn't decrypt the data. see my code below. I wanted to decrypt the data on other pages. Thanks in advance!

```
$base64 = "AAA";

$cipher = new Crypt_AES(); 
$cipher->setKey('QrzMwvH7zmVn5Kzu%ks8GSTWzyLJu#Ck!^f%-UpXefuYBhv^%qLwYsuPx0d&zmNo');
$cipher->setIV(crypt_random_string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));
echo $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($base64); 


$cipher = new Crypt_AES(); 
$cipher->setKey('QrzMwvH7zmVn5Kzu%ks8GSTWzyLJu#Ck!^f%-UpXefuYBhv^%qLwYsuPx0d&zmNo');
$cipher->setIV(crypt_random_string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));
echo 'decrypted:'.  $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);
```

**Result**

%�NK�y�0�k�:decrypted:

**Update:**

Does this mean that It's necessary to keep a list of Initialization Vector in order to decrypt the data?

**Update:**

I've decided to use Lumen Framework. Lumen has a built-in encrpytion feature that handles IV and other encyrption technical stuff. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a different IV in both cases - you need to be using the same IV. Try this:

```
$base64 = "AAA";
$iv = crypt_random_string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3);

$cipher = new Crypt_AES(); 
$cipher->setKey('QrzMwvH7zmVn5Kzu%ks8GSTWzyLJu#Ck!^f%-UpXefuYBhv^%qLwYsuPx0d&zmNo');
$cipher->setIV($iv);
echo $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($base64); 


$cipher = new Crypt_AES(); 
$cipher->setKey('QrzMwvH7zmVn5Kzu%ks8GSTWzyLJu#Ck!^f%-UpXefuYBhv^%qLwYsuPx0d&zmNo');
$cipher->setIV($iv);
echo 'decrypted:'.  $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);
```

Comment: Would there be an issue with regards the security if I use astatic IV?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Do not use a static IV because if you encrypt the same messages again the encrypted data will be the same and that leaks information.

Comment: @zaph thanks! I agree and I've done my research on this too. I've also compared diffrent libraries/plugin and it's best if the IV is dynamic. Making it dynamic is challenging but more secure. Anyway, i've decided to use lumen framework. It has built-in encryption. So no need to dig deeper  in this.

Comment: @bwaaaaaa From what I can tell that choice seems very good, it even does encryption authentication and uses the OpenSSL library.

Comment: @zaph - phpseclib uses the OpenSSL library, as well, if it's available. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

Use a randomly generated IV for encryption. The IV does not need to be secret so just prefix the encrypted data with the IV. Then the IV is available for decryption.

The encryption key `'QrzMwvH7zmVn5Kzu%ks8GSTWzyLJu#Ck!^f%-UpXefuYBhv^%qLwYsuPx0d&zmNo'` is 512-bits (64-bytes) but there are only three AES key sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a library. Why don't you use `openssl_encrypt()`?

**For Encrypting:**

```
openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $key);
```

**Parameters:**

1. `$text`: The Text You Want To Encrypt.
2. `$method`: The method you will use for encrypting. I use `AES-256-ECB` mostly.
3. `$key`: The key you use for encrypting.

**Example:**

```
$data = openssl_encrypt('Hello', 'AES-256-ECB' 'test');
```

**Decrypting:**

```
openssl_decrypt($encrypted_text, $method, $key);
```

**Parameters:**

1. `$encrypted_text`: The Text Encrypted.
2. `$method`: The method you will use for decrypting.
3. `$key`: The key to decrypt the text.

**Example:**

```
openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-ECB', 'test');
```

Comment: I've tried using it before I decided to use a library. I encountered an error/warning saying that I need an Initialization Vector, which I don't have a clue what it is.

Comment: there is a very good example on [here](http://creepergaming.net/encrypt) uses openssl

Comment: @bwaaaaaa That just means you need to take a break to study encryption. Just getting encryption and decryption working does not provide security unless it is used properly.